# Distinct keyword in linq query

Tags: linq

my linq query returns duplicate records like below, how i have to use distinct keyword in this linq query.

```
var draft_recieved = from df in _DataContext.tblDrafts
                     from dfBody in _DataContext.DraftBodies
                     from sendUser in _DataContext.tblSends

                     where (df.DraftId == dfBody.DraftID) && (df.DraftId == sendUser.DraftId) &&
                     (sendUser.ToEmailId == (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey)
                     select new

                     {
                         subject = dfBody.Subject,
                         draftid = df.DraftId
                     };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Distinct()` has to be applied as an extension method.

```
var draft_recieved = (from df in _DataContext.tblDrafts
                 from dfBody in _DataContext.DraftBodies
                 from sendUser in _DataContext.tblSends

                 where (df.DraftId == dfBody.DraftID) && (df.DraftId == sendUser.DraftId) &&
                 (sendUser.ToEmailId == (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey)
                 select new

                 {
                     subject = dfBody.Subject,
                     draftid = df.DraftId
                 }).Distinct();
```

Comment: Ah that's sucks, but thanks for answer will have to use it.